# How to get an element in center of list at scroll event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of numbers which can scroll vertically. All I want it to get element which placed in center of that list when scroll event fires.

For ex. in this screen I want to get 8

[image]

Here is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-monad-fqowxt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-leaf-mzhrzy?file=/src/App.js:95-729) using the api - [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

```
export default function App() {
  const refList = useRef();

  function onScroll({ target }) {
    // get the computed dimension of the list
    const { height, width, x, y } = target.getBoundingClientRect();

    // adding x and y as offsets. You may skip this
    const x1 = (width + x) / 2;
    const y1 = (height + y) / 2;

    console.log(document.elementFromPoint(x1, y1)); // prints the element from given point
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul
        ref={refList}
        onScroll={onScroll}
      >
        {NUMBERS.map((i) => (
          <li key={i}>{i}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```